# fastest way to print new line in std out in C language?

Tags: c, io

So I am solving questions on codechef(programming competition platform) and this specific question has a lot of I/O with every result to be printed in a new line on the console. Without printing results in new line the program execution takes about .3 seconds but with a new line its taking around 1.3 seconds with 1 second being the limit for program execution.

My question is that is it possible to print new line on console faster??

I am using putchar_unlocked and using this custom function for output as specified below. The compiler is gcc 4.8.1

```
#define pc(x) putchar_unlocked(x);
inline void writeInt (int n)
{
    int N = n, rev, count = 0;
    rev = N;
    if (N == 0) {
      pc('0'); 
      pc('\n'); 
      return;
    }
    while ((rev % 10) == 0) {
      count++;
      rev /= 10;
      //obtain the count of the number of 0s
    }
    rev = 0;
    while (N != 0) { 
      rev = (rev<<3) + (rev<<1) + N % 10;
      N /= 10;
      //store reverse of N in rev
    }  
    while (rev != 0) {
      pc(rev % 10 + '0'); 
      rev /= 10;
    }
    while (count--) pc('0');
    pc('\n'); //this line prints new line and the reason for 1 second delay!
}
```

Comment: For what I can read from comments, you need to determine how many 0s there are in that number. That can be improved with bitwise operations; it'd off-topic, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `stdout` is line-buffered. Means that a system call `write` is invoked if there is a newline in the buffer.

Change stdout buffering to fully buffered:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 0);
```

And flush your output at the end:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: i havent used it before and am  a little confused implementing it. Is it like standalone function to be called in the beginning of program to fully buffer the stdout and call fflush at the end to clear it?? Also i have to compile on gcc so i am not too sure whether fflush works.

Comment: @Danny Both `setvbuf` and `fflush` are part of the C standard library subsection `stdio`, so they are generally available on all mainstream systems. And yes, you would call `setvbuf` at the beginning and `fflush` at the end of your function. Optionally if your process exits normally then `fflush` will be called before it exits.

Comment: The output will be flushed when the file is closed as the program ends, so the `fflush()` is not strictly necessary, though it won't do measurable harm to the performance.